# Should we stop using Zend WinEnabler?

Tags: php, zend-server

(This question is over 6 years old and probably no longer has any relevance.)

Our system uses Zend WinEnabler.

- Do you use it?
- Is it obsolete?
- Should we stop using it?
- Is it known to cause handle/memory leaks?

Here is an (old) introduction to it: [PHP Creators Unveil New Product that Makes PHP Truly Viable for Windows Environments](http://personalweb.about.com/b/2004/03/29/zend-announces-winenabler-enabling-php-for-windows-environments.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Zend appears to not be selling it anymore and all its functionality is available for free (through FastCGI), I would say so.  Look at the [Zend Core](http://www.zend.com/en/products/core/) ([installing Zend Core](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/272/installing-php-on-windows-vista-with-fastcgi/)) if you really want to run PHP on Windows.  But really, you should be asking yourself why you are running PHP on Windows at all (we used to do it, and the headaches where enormous, especially since nobody else was doing it).